# Remove duplicates entries from autocomplete filter - Javascript

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, yadcf

If you type to filter autocomplete function returns duplicates values or more.

[image: duplicates]

This happens because I have 2 text delimiters inside my code (`,` and `-`).

```
            column_number: 2,
            text_data_delimiter: /(\s-\s)|,/,
            filter_type: "auto_complete"
```

But I wish keep both text delimiters and I want delete duplicates values in autocomplete filter.
This is demo: [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chcLmmps/12/)
This is a javascript code fragment:

```
var oTable;
$(document).ready(function () {
    oTable = $('#example').dataTable().yadcf([{
        column_number: 0
    }, {
        column_number: 3,
        filter_type: "range_number_slider",
        filter_container_id: "external_filter_container"
    }, {
        column_number: 2,
        text_data_delimiter: /(\s-\s)|,/,
        filter_type: "auto_complete"
    }, {
        column_number: 1,
        text_data_delimiter: /(\s-\s)|,/,
        filter_type: "auto_complete"
    }, {
        column_number: 4,
        column_data_type: "html",
        html_data_type: "text",
        filter_default_label: "Select tag",
        filter_type: "auto_complete"
    }]);
```